# How to write a javascript to discern between specific guests for a "guest list" variable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

So this isn't anything crazy as I am just starting out with coding. I just learned about if else statements and then variable arrays. I made a "guest list" code that will either welcome the guest or tell them to leave, if their name is in the variable array. I have that down fine. But I'm trying to make it so that one specific person when prompted for their name will be greeted differently than the others, without it also executing the other code. I've gotten it to work, but it'll say "hello, sir!" and then say "you can't enter!" right after. The snippet I have attached is the base working idea, and the image shows what I want to add. I'm just really trying to get down these if else statements because I think these will be really helpful in the long run. I effectively want this to recognize the name, then if the name is on the normal list, greet them. If it's on the owner list, respectful greeting. And if on neither, tell them to leave, without double responses.

```js
var guestList = ["John", "Tony", "Mark", "Jones", "Mike"];
var ownerList = ["Cole"];


var guestName = prompt("What is your name?");

//This is the code I'm trying to add 
if (ownerList.includes("guestName")) {
  alert("Hello, Sir!")
}

if (guestList.includes(guestName)) {
  alert("Hello, and welcome!")
} else {

  alert("You shall not pass!");
}
```

Comment: _"I've gotten it to work, but it'll say "hello, owner!" and then say "you can't enter!" right after."_ - your code doesn't do that.

Comment: So add another check for the owner....

Comment: @Andy  When I said that I meant that in previous iterations, that was the best I could do. I could get it to double up or do nothing at all.

Comment: `ownerList` will never include the string "guestName."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you check whether `ownerList` includes `guestName`, then check whether `guestList` includes it.

In your example, `"Cole"` is in `ownerList` but not in `guestList`, so it alerts "Hello, Sir!" and "You shall not pass!".

You should instead only check whether `guestList` includes the prompt answer if `ownerList` does not include it. This can be done by chaining the `if` statements with the use of `else if`.

<sup>Note: You are also checking whether `ownerList` includes `"guestName"` instead of the variable `guestName`.</sup>

```js
var guestList = ["John", "Tony", "Mark", "Jones", "Mike"];
var ownerList = ["Cole"];


var guestName = prompt("What is your name?");

//This is the code I'm trying to add 
if (ownerList.includes(guestName)) {
  alert("Hello, Sir!")
} else if (guestList.includes(guestName)) {
  alert("Hello, and welcome!")
} else {

  alert("You shall not pass!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**I just tried the same but there iśno bug i just write that wrong `"guesName"` instead of guestName **

var guestList = ["John", "Tony", "Mark", "Jones", "Mike"];
var ownerList = ["Cole","Dale"];


var guestName = prompt("What is your name?");

if (ownerList.includes(guestName)) {
  alert("Hello, Sir!")
}

else if (guestList.includes(guestName)) {
  alert("Hello, and welcome!")
} else {

  alert("You shall not pass!");
}
```